# HTML5 save canvas to file on server

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i need to create a component using html5 canvas that given an image the user can paint on it and directly (via a kind of save button) upload it's customized version on the server.

Can i use html canvas for it ?
Any suggestion ?

thx in advance

Comment: Related: [Draw image on canvas from image data stored in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77591955/draw-image-on-canvas-from-image-data-stored-in-database/77592106#77592106)

Answer (score 6):

You can get the image as data-url like this:

```
var dataUrl = document.getElementById('your-canvas').toDataURL();
```

You could then send this (very long string) to the server and save it to a file after decoding it (it is encoded in base64).

**EDIT:** Remember to submit this via `POST`, as suggested in the comments. `GET` has some length-limits in various browsers, so its likely to exceed those limits with such a huge amout of data.

Comment: Remember to use `POST` as the Ajax method. A GET might break due to its size.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is currently dead-on-arrival for Android (up to and including 2.3).  Please star this issue - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7901