# need to upload the contents of HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML5 canvas where the user has created an image. This is for an image drawing program. I now need to grab the canvas and post it to my server. I also need to post a set of key/value pairs along with the image. Could someone help me with how this is supposed to be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 save canvas to file on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684347/html5-save-canvas-to-file-on-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf) for how to use `toDataURL` to turn your canvas into an image (encoded as a [data URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)) .

Consult the [MDN Ajax tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started) to learn how to send data to your server asynchronously.